# Hibernate + Spring hibernate.show_sql don't show batch queries together

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I'm using Spring + Hibernate configured this way,

```
  private Properties hibernateProperties() {
    Properties hibernateProperties = new Properties();
    hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "none");
    hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", jdbcHibernateDialect);
    hibernateProperties.put("hibernate.show_sql", hibernateShowSql);
    hibernateProperties.put("hibernate.format_sql", true);
    hibernateProperties.put("hibernate.use_sql_comments", true);
    hibernateProperties.put("hibernate.jdbc.batch_size", 50);
    hibernateProperties.put("hibernate.order_inserts", true);
    hibernateProperties.put("hibernate.order_updates", true);
    hibernateProperties.put("hibernate.batch_versioned_data", true);
    hibernateProperties.put("hibernate.connection.provider_disables_autocommit", !oltpAutoCommit);
    hibernateProperties.put("hibernate.default_schema", defaultSchema);
    hibernateProperties.put("hibernate.generate_statistics", true);
    return hibernateProperties;
  }
```

Now, the batching does work, I can see it in the logs printed by the statistics property, but the queries them selfs printed separately (see code below), how can I reflect the batching in the logs?

```
Hibernate: 
    /* update
        com.salesforce.atrium.core.model.entity.admin.TenantUser */ update
            atrium_oltp.tenant_users 
        set
            create_time=?,
            is_deleted=?,
            update_time=?,
            access_token=?,
            access_token_expiration_time=?,
            business_unit_id=?,
            is_default_tenant=?,
            refresh_token=?,
            slack_user_id=?,
            tenant_id=?,
            user_id=? 
        where
            id=?
Hibernate: 
    /* update
        com.salesforce.atrium.core.model.entity.admin.TenantUser */ update
            atrium_oltp.tenant_users 
        set
            create_time=?,
            is_deleted=?,
            update_time=?,
            access_token=?,
            access_token_expiration_time=?,
            business_unit_id=?,
            is_default_tenant=?,
            refresh_token=?,
            slack_user_id=?,
            tenant_id=?,
            user_id=? 
        where
            id=?
20:43:32.729 [qtp2100728289-87] INFO  o.h.e.i.StatisticalLoggingSessionEventListener - Session Metrics {
    444670 nanoseconds spent acquiring 1 JDBC connections;
    0 nanoseconds spent releasing 0 JDBC connections;
    2831281 nanoseconds spent preparing 7 JDBC statements;
    9873973 nanoseconds spent executing 4 JDBC statements;
    3735970 nanoseconds spent executing 3 JDBC batches;
    0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C puts;
    0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C hits;
    0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C misses;
    27744835 nanoseconds spent executing 1 flushes (flushing a total of 9 entities and 1 collections);
    16938166 nanoseconds spent executing 3 partial-flushes (flushing a total of 6 entities and 6 collections)
```

=== === ====== === ====== === ====== === ====== === ====== === ====== === ===
=== === ====== === ====== === ====== === ====== === ===

Answer (score 4):

Hibernate logs the batch handling to the `org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch` category. If you set the level to debug, you will see the following messages in your log:

```
08:59:19,114 DEBUG [org.hibernate.SQL] - insert into Author (firstName, lastName, version, id) values (?, ?, ?, ?)
08:59:19,119 DEBUG [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.AbstractBatchImpl] - Reusing batch statement
08:59:19,119 DEBUG [org.hibernate.SQL] - insert into Author (firstName, lastName, version, id) values (?, ?, ?, ?)
08:59:19,119 DEBUG [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.AbstractBatchImpl] - Reusing batch statement
08:59:19,119 DEBUG [org.hibernate.SQL] - insert into Author (firstName, lastName, version, id) values (?, ?, ?, ?)
08:59:19,119 DEBUG [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.AbstractBatchImpl] - Reusing batch statement
08:59:19,120 DEBUG [org.hibernate.SQL] - insert into Author (firstName, lastName, version, id) values (?, ?, ?, ?)
08:59:19,120 DEBUG [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.AbstractBatchImpl] - Reusing batch statement
08:59:19,120 DEBUG [org.hibernate.SQL] - insert into Author (firstName, lastName, version, id) values (?, ?, ?, ?)
08:59:19,120 DEBUG [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.BatchingBatch] - Executing batch size: 5
```

I also recommend not using Hibernate's `hibernate.show_sql` parameter. It's more efficient to activate the logging of SQL statements by setting the category `org.hibernate.SQL` to `debug` in your [logging configuration](https://thorben-janssen.com/spring-data-jpa-logging/#Recommended_Configuration_for_Development).